# How can I replace a dynamic class with a variable?

Tags: php, symfony, class, oop, variables

I would like to replace my class with a variable:

```
$type = "TextType";

$formBuilder->add($name, TextType::class, array('attr' => array('class' => 'form-control'), 'data' => $dataItem, 'mapped' => false, 'label' => $name));
```

This is my approach:

```
$formBuilder->add($name, $type::class, array('attr' => array('class' => 'form-control'), 'data' => $dataItem, 'mapped' => false, 'label' => $name));
```

I get the error:

> Compile Error: Dynamic class names are not allowed in compile-time
>   ::class fetch

But how can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is telling you you can't use dynamic class names.

So you can't.

Use the class name directly in the `add()` call. You can even create the variable holding the fully qualified class name before, if you really need to:

```php
$class = TextType::class;

$formBuilder->add($name, $class,
     [
          'attr'   => ['class' => 'form-control'],
          'data'   => $dataItem,
          'mapped' => false,
          'label'  => $name
     ]
);
```

Comment: You know, I want to store different classes in the database. Like this: https://i.imgur.com/kSXDfsM.png  so I can replace it for every item. But it is not working

Comment: You know what I try to do?

Comment: I store it exactly like this in the database `TextType::class` but when I want to use it, the error is `Could not load type "TextType::class": class does not exist.`

Comment: If you really need to do this, don't store `TextType::class`. Store the fully qualified class name. E.g. `App\Form\TextType`.

Comment: Ah, ok, I understand. So this is actually what I am looking for! I should not write `TextType::class`  then. Instead `App\Form\TextType`. Thank you!

Comment: I am sorry to ask, for you it is a stupid question I guess, but how can I actually find out what is the correct link for TextType `Could not load type "App\Form\TextType": class does not exist.`

Comment: I am implementing it like this `use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;`

Comment: That's a made up name, I don't know your system. You should use the one that you are actually using on your application. Look for the class in your code. It's fully qualified name will be the namespace declaration on top + the class name.

Comment: Then the class name is `Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType`.